# Healthbar Colorcalculation

Tags: javascript, game-development

I found a very pretty code for a healthbar.

But I do not really understand how the color-calculation works.

I would be glad if any of you could explain the calculation to me.

```
var display = document.getElementById('display').getContext('2d');

drawHealthbar(display, 10, 10, 500, 50, 5, 5);

function drawHealthbar(canvas, x, y, width, height, health, max_health) {
  if (health >= max_health) {
    health = max_health;
  }

  if (health <= 0) {
    health = 0;
  }

  canvas.fillStyle = '#000000';
  canvas.fillRect(x, y, width, height);

  var colorNumber = Math.round((1 - (health / max_health)) * 0xff) * 0x10000 + Math.round((health / max_health) * 0xff) * 0x100;
  var colorString = colorNumber.toString(16);

  if (colorNumber >= 0x100000) {
    canvas.fillStyle = '#' + colorString;
  } else if (colorNumber << 0x100000 && colorNumber >= 0x10000) {
    canvas.fillStyle = '#0' + colorString;
  } else if (colorNumber << 0x10000) {
    canvas.fillStyle = '#00' + colorString;
  }

  canvas.fillRect(x + 1, y + 1, (health / max_health) * (width - 2), height - 2);
}
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because SO isn't a code explaining service.

Comment: it's an interpolation between red and green: `var t = health / max_health; console.log({t, red: 255 - t*255, green: t*255, hex: "#" +  ((255 - t*255)<<16 | (t*255) << 8).toString(16).padStart(6, 0) });`

Answer (score 1):

### Background

Colours are normally displayed as hexidecimal RGB values. This means that when you see a colour described as `#456BC9`, this means the Red value is `45`, the Green value is `6B`, and the Blue value is `C9`.

Hexidecimal means instead of numbers going `0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11...` they instead go `0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, A, B, C, D E, F, 10, 11...` (ie there are 16 'numbers' rather than 10). This is otherwise referred to as "base-16" (as opposed to the decimal system which is base-10).

---

### Code Explanation

```
var colorNumber = Math.round((1 - (health / max_health)) * 0xff) * 0x10000 + Math.round((health / max_health) * 0xff) * 0x100;
```

This bit of code is generating a hexidecimal number based on the user's health. In a lot of programming languages, you show that a number is hexidecimal by prefixing it with `0x`.

---

```
var colorString = colorNumber.toString(16);
```

This bit of code is turning that number into a string, but keeping the hexidecimal (base 16) format.

---

```
if (colorNumber >= 0x100000) {
    canvas.fillStyle = '#' + colorString;
  } else if (colorNumber << 0x100000 && colorNumber >= 0x10000) {
    canvas.fillStyle = '#0' + colorString;
  } else if (colorNumber << 0x10000) {
    canvas.fillStyle = '#00' + colorString;
  }
```

This part is adding the `#` symbol in the correct place, so that the final string is a `#` followed by 6 numbers/letters.

---

The rest of the code is calculating the health or filling the rectangle based on the fillStyle just defined.